# find content of files with other text and combination of xml tags, grep in grep?

Tags: grep, search

I have a lot of files that match a grep 'xmltag' and 'subtag'.

```
random xml
needed_text
random xml
<xmltag>
<subtag>content</subtag>
</xmltag>
```

I want to search for files that match another text 'needed_text'.

The output should contain 'content' at the very least, but complete lines would also be acceptable:

```
<xmltag>
     <subtag>content</subtag>
</xmltag>
```

xmltag and subtag maybe on same or on different lines

```
grep -rl "needed_text" *
```

gives a list of file names i need as input for the second part, but how do i feed that to another grep (or other command) and how do i make sure it finds only the combination of xmltag and subtag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the list of files to another command, you'd use `xargs`. For it to be reliable, you need the `-0` option as supported by most modern implementations, and the list of file paths must be passed NUL-delimited (using the `-Z` option with GNU `grep` or compatible).

```
grep -rlZ "needed_text" . |
  xargs -r0 pcregrep -Mo '(?s)<xmltag>.*?</xmltag>'
```

(assuming there are no nested `<xmltag>`s and the `<xmltag>`s won't occur in CDATA, and the usual caveats associated with parsing XML with regexps).

If the files are proper XML files, you can use XML aware tools like `xmllint`, `xpath`, `xmlstarlet` instead of `pcregrep` to extract the tags you want.

```
grep -rlZ "needed_text" . |
  xargs -r0 xpath -e //xmltag
```

Or for only the `xmltag`s that have at least one `subtag`:

```
grep -rlZ "needed_text" . |
  xargs -r0 xpath -e //xmltag/subtag/..
```

(here using the `xpath` shipped with the `XML::XPath` perl module).